# Search filters not working when using AND operator on EWS?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to filter through emails using two filters: emails sent TODAY and emails from a specific recipient.
I tried the following approach:

```
DateTime searchdate = DateTime.Today;
            SearchFilter greaterthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, searchdate);
            SearchFilter lessthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, searchdate.AddHours(24));
            SearchFilter senderFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.From, "some-email-here@domain.com");
            SearchFilter dateFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, greaterthanfilter, lessthanfilter);
            SearchFilter allFilters = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, dateFilter, senderFilter);
            Folder folder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
            FindItemsResults<Item> results = folder.FindItems(allFilters, new ItemView(50));
            foreach(Item i in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.Subject);
            }
```

If I use the filters separately, everything works fine. I either get the emails filtered by the sender or the emails filtered by the received date. If I change the `LogicalOperator` to `OR`, everythings works great as well.
For some reason, when I add the `LogicalOperator.And`, no emails are returned.

If you know a better way, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @glen-scales advised, I went and looked at query strings which at first, did not help me out because they weren't solving the issue either!
Turns out it was a problem of how you write the query string! This worked perfectly for me:

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(folder.Id, "from:email@domain.com AND Received:Today", new ItemView(20));
```

Whereas this did not work at all:

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(folder.Id, "(from:email@domain.com) AND (Received:Today)", new ItemView(20));
```

If you did not notice, the difference is the use of the parentheses (although they should not be problematic, I believe).

For further documentation on query strings, refer to the following link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ee693615%28v%3dexchg.140%29

Comment: How to use NOT operator in querystring?

Answer (score 1):

Your search filter works fine when i test it, as an alternative you could use a QueryString which should quicker if nothing else https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/querystring-querystringtypeand AQS/KQL eg

```
(Received:today) AND (From:'user@domain.com')
```

You could simplify your SearchFilters a little if your only after message that where sent/received today the lessthanfilter is redundant (as the date is in the future)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! Weird, why doesn't it work for me? Also, the link you provided gives a 404 error. Noted for the ```lessthanfilter```, I will try removing it. I do not see how I can use a query string though, can you clarify?